# Find the real values of $m$ such that $a \leq b \leq c$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

> Given a   system of equations (where $m$ is a real number),
>
> $(a + b) = 2m^2$ ,  $(b+ c) = 6m$ , $(c + a) = 2$ , find the real values of $m$ such that $a \leq b \leq c.$

**What I Tried** :- I tried to do it like this.

Suppose the equations are marked as $x,y,z$ in that order. Then by doing $(x - y + z)$ I get :-

$$2a = 2m^2 - 6m + 2$$
$$\rightarrow a = m^2 - 3m + 1$$

Now I find that $m = \frac{3}{2}$ is a solution iff $a = -\frac{5}{4}$ .
From $a$ and $m$, I can deduce that $b = \frac{23}{4}$ and $c = \frac{13}{4}$ , which is not possible as it is given that $a \leq b \leq c$. So we can say that $m = \frac{3}{2}$ is not a solution.

I guess my work is actually fine, but the problem is that this is not the only answer at all. I have got some more cases to check with, [such as what would have happened if we had done $(x + y + z)$ or $(-x + -y + -z)$ $?$] and it is seeming like a very tiring work dealing with a lot of cases like that and finding what $m$ satisfies and what $m$ does not, I believe there is some more easier solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are the answers given in any textbook or workbook (or whatever you referred to get this question) ?

Comment: No, but does it matter?

Comment: Probably, because the solutions and the roads to it will be there in the textbook (or the other books mentioned).

Comment: This question is from a practice paper , so you can expect no solutions from it for now.

Comment: Wow... which means that the solution is not currently with you..

Comment: When will you have the access to the solutions ?

Comment: Or was that paper from the net ?

Comment: @Spectre, I don't have access to the solutions , I have to hunt for them :) . In simple words, I have to find this without a solution even if you want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

- $(a + b) = 2m^2 \implies a=2m^2-b$
- $(c + a) = 2 \implies c=2-a$
- $(b+ c) = 6m \implies b=6m-c=6m-2+a$

therefore

- $a=m^2-3m+1$
- $b=m^2+3m-1$
- $c=-m^2+3m+1$

and

$$a  \leq b \leq c \iff m^2-3m+1\le m^2+3m-1\le -m^2+3m+1$$

$$ m^2-3m\le m^2-1\le 0 \iff \frac13 \le m \le 1$$

Comment: Congrats, @user !

Comment: Oh wait, uh oh I never thought of this before, Jeez . Does this give all the real values for m?

Comment: Jeez ? What's that ?

Comment: @Anonymous It seems a natural way to me, once we have $a,b,c$ in terms of $m$, we can find the conditions on $m$.

Comment: I was just posting the same! No need now :) All values between 1/3 and 1 work.

Comment: Yeah @user , you know I just think easy things in a complicated way and get stuck on it forever.

Comment: actually adding all of them, gives the value for (a+b+c) and then subtract each one to get $a, b, c$

Comment: @MathLover , then I guess I would have done $(x + y + z)$ before .

Comment: @Anonymous Yes that gives you $a+b+c = m^2+3m+1$ and then subtracting each one $(b+c), (c+a), (a+b)$ gives you $a, b, c$